# Open several layouts from a single activity (listview)

Tags: android, listview, layout

I created a list of drugs in my main activity using a ListView in Android Studio.
Since drugs are many and have same characteristics (indication, contraindication, posology) I'd like to know if there is an alternative to create an activity for each drug. In other words: is it possible to open different layouts from one single activity? Is it possible to create a "template" layout and insert only the contents (posology and so on...)? I tried with Fragment but I failed miserably. Alternatively, creating a lot of activity can slow down my application? Thank you (I apologyze for my terrible english grammar)

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest doing is creating something like a DrugDetail activity which you pass information about the drug to. This means instead of creating loads of activities for every drug you just create one activity and pass it all the drugs information.

So what you would do is set an onItemClickListener onto your drug listview the. Inside that listener method have something like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, DrugDetail.class);
intent.putExtra("drugName", "drugnamestring");
intent.putExtra("drugDescription", "drugDescriptionString");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you Andy I'm gonna try your hint and I'll let you know later.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the best practice is creating base layout (extends common layouts e.g. FrameLayout or RelativeLayout) witch you will inflate in your own class witch will extends ListView class for all items of this custom ListView. When user clicks on list's item it extends and shows him all information about particular drug. This video is all you need, enjoy! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwE61B56pVQ

Comment: Dear Dev, thank you for your quick answer. I watched your video and I want to compliment your job that is very nice both for contents and quality. In my App I'd prefer to open different layout in a different screen instead of scroll them down, because number of drugs is very high and I don't want to see all informations in sigle layout. Have you got other ideas?